# How to save parameters on local server when using remote grpc session on Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I first start a grpc server in server A.

```
server = tf.train.Server.create_local_server()
server.join()
```

Then I execute the training process on server B:

```
sess = tf.Session("grpc://172.31.222.83:34217")
sess.run(init)

for i in range(1000):
    _, l = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed)

saver.save(sess, './ckpts/model')
```

When the training process is finished, I find the checkpoints have saved on server A. But I want server A just used as **computational node**. That is to say, I want the parameters are all saved on server B, server A is used only to compute. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility.

```
service TrainerService {
    rpc Train(TrainRequest) returns (TrainResponse);
}

func (s *trainerServer) Train(..., req *pb.TrainRequest) (resp *pb.TrainResponse) {
    return &pb.TrainResponse{tensorTrainer.Train(req.data)}
}
```

Here is another

```
service TrainerService {
    rpc Train(TrainRequest) returns (TrainResponse);
    rpc Results(ResultsRequest) returns (ResultsResponse);
}

func (s *trainerServer) Train(..., req *pb.TrainRequest) (resp *pb.TrainResponse) {
    session, err := NewTrainingSession(req.data)
    if err != nil { panic() }
    go session.Train()
    return &pb.TrainResponse{session.id}
}

func (s *trainerServer) Results(..., req *pb.ResultsRequest) (resp *pb.ResultsResponse) {
    results, err := GetResults(req.id)
    if err != nil { panic() }
    return &pb.ResultsResponse{results}
}
```

The client can call `Train` and poll `Results` until success. Perhaps `TrainResponse` returns an estimate.